# "no match for 'operator>>'" error for STL classes like vector, but not for custom classes

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, istream

I'm able to overload operator>> for my own classes, but I get this

`error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream_iterator<std::vector<int> >::istream_type’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>’} and ‘std::vector<int>’)`

when I try to do it for a std::vector.  I don't understand the error.  Why does it work for my MyClass but not a std::vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass { std::vector<int> v; };
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyClass& mc) {
  std::string token;
  is >> token;
  for (auto x : token) mc.v.push_back(x);
  return is;
}
void f1(std::istream_iterator<MyClass>& it) {}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<int>& v) {
  std::string token;
  is >> token;
  for (auto x : token) v.push_back(x);
  return is;
}
void f2(std::istream_iterator<std::vector<int>>& it) {}

int main() {
  // std::istream_iterator<MyClass> it(std::cin);
  // f1(it);
  // works when uncommented

  std::istream_iterator<std::vector<int>> it(std::cin);
  f2(it);
  // error
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `f2` supposed to be? Why are you pushing `char` to an `int` vector?

Comment: Ah, another victim of ADL. I can't find a duplicate right now, but (simplifying) - operator overload must be in the namespace of one of the operands, and since you cannot add anything to `namespace std`, you are out of luck.

Comment: in general it can be problematic to overload operators for types that arent yours. If you want to use `istream_iterator` with a `std::vector` then your `MyClass` is already a way to do that. If you don't like that `MyClass` owns the vector you can make the member a pointer or reference

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, re: "and since you cannot add anything to namespace std", can't I?  I'm guessing this is ill-advised, but it actually compiles and works if I wrap the `operator>>` overload in `namespace std {}`.

Comment: @cosmo_kramer: The standard places **no** requirements on an implementation that is given a program that adds to `std`.  If *this* version of *this* compiler with *this* version of *this* standard library with *these* command-line options on *this* platform with *this* input happens to do something good, that’s great, but in the absence of separately documented promises from your implementation (which do exist in some cases: see `-fwrapv`) it must be considered an **accident** that mustn’t ever be relied upon.  (So, yes, “ill-advised”.)