# std::inner_product doesn't compile with specific std::vector + and * operator overloads

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, operator-overloading, std

I'm trying to write a small linear algebra library in C++, purely for educational purposes. I chose to use as much of the standard library as possible to maximize my learning. I'm trying to implement matrix-vector multiplication using `std::inner_product`. (Matrices are in column-major order).

I have the following code, which does not compile in the lastest version of GCC (11.1.0 at the time of this writing):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// copy-pasted from <numeric>, but changed identifier
template<typename _InputIterator1, typename _InputIterator2, typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp
    inner_product2(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1,
          _InputIterator2 __first2, _Tp __init)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator1>)
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator2>)
      __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first1, __last1);

      for (; __first1 != __last1; ++__first1, (void)++__first2)
    __init = __init + (*__first1 * *__first2);
      return __init;
    }

struct custom_int {
    int x;
    custom_int(): x(0) {}
    custom_int(int x): x(x) {}
    custom_int& operator+=(const custom_int& y) { x += y.x; return *this; }
    custom_int& operator*=(const custom_int& y) { x *= y.x; return *this; }
};
using int_t = int;
vector<int_t> operator+(vector<int_t> u, const vector<int_t>& v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        u[i] += v[i];
    }
    return u;
}
vector<int_t> operator*(vector<int_t> v, const int_t& scalar) { 
    for(auto& vi : v) {
        vi *= scalar;
    }
    return v;
}
int main() {
    vector<vector<int_t>> A = {{2, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};
    vector<int_t> b = {3, 2, 2};
    inner_product(A.begin(), A.end(), b.begin(), vector<int_t>(A[0].size()));
    return 0;
}
```

However, doing one of the following makes it compile:

1. Changing `using int_t = int;` into `using int_t = custom_int;`.
2. Changing `inner_product(A.begin(), A.end(), b.begin(), vector<int_t>(A[0].size()));` into `inner_product2(A.begin(), A.end(), b.begin(), vector<int_t>(A[0].size()));`

Why does this happen?

Comment: There might be some problem related to namespaces. IIRC, operators should generally be defined in the same namespace as the type of their operands. In your case, your `operator+` acts on `std::vector` operands, however, it is defined outside of the `std` namespace. Live demo of this problem: https://godbolt.org/z/K9E4chKMq.

Comment: this is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/70289006/4117728. Unfortunately duplicates arent easy to find. My rule of thumb to avoid the problem: Don't overload operators for types you don't own. Here you can use a `my_vector` with a `std::vector` as member that implements the operators as you wish

Comment: You are aware there is a variant of `std::inner_product()` that accepts two additional arguments? - one a function object representing addition, and the other a function object representing multiplication.    You can probably use that in some way, rather than modifying the (compiler-specific) implementation of the `std::inner_product()` that doesn't accept those arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think I understand now. The duplicate question linked by @463035818_is_not_a_number led me to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl, which I should read to understand why it works when the type parameter of `std::vector` is custom.

Comment: @Peter I was hoping that overloading the operators that `std::inner_product` depended on sufficed. (And those overloads are useful for other purposes anyway.) I wasn't intending to modify the compiler-specific implementation. It's just there to demonstrate my ignorance of "the namespace matters when overloading operators." Oh well, I guess I have to go a more roundabout way. Good suggestion though.